# If statement not waiting for async function to execute

Tags: javascript

I want my program to execute the code in the second else statement when reponse equals to 0.

However, it seems like it's not waiting for the function to complete and always executes what's in the true branch.

I'm not really familiar with async/await and would appreciate some guidance here.

```
 async function fetchInvoice(currentValue, callback) {
   let requestData = basePayload;
   requestData.body = //requestbody;
        
   let productData = await fetch(baseUrl, requestData);
   let jsonData = await productData.json();
        
   if (await jsonData.result.records.length !== 0) {
     //code
   } else {
     return false;
   }
 };
        
 if (fetchInvoice(myParameter)) {
   //code
 } else {
   //code
 }
```

Comment: Typo.  You forgot the parentheses to *invoke* `myFunction`... `if (myFunction())`

Comment: Thanks, there is no typo in the original code though.

Comment: In what other ways does this moving target differ from "the original code"?  Where are you invoking any asynchronous operation at all?  Where do you ever define `response` or set a value to it?  Which `if/else` structure are you referring to?  Did you just forget to *await* `myFunction()`?  Did you just forget to `return true` from `myFunction`?  Instead of showing us text that might kind of look like the code you're using, please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicate specifically what problem you are observing in that example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) two issues...

First, `myFunction` never returns `true`.  For any logical condition where you want the function to return `true`, add a return statement:

```
return true;
```

Otherwise, if the function doesn't return anything, its result is `undefined` which is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Second, you forgot to *await* the `async` function:

```
if (await fetchInvoice(myParameter)) {
  //code
} else {
  //code
}
```

Or, if this code is executing in a context which can't use `await` (such as top-level code in a browser) then you can follow up the Promise with `.then`:

```
fetchInvoice(myParameter).then(x => {
  if (x) {
    //code
  } else {
    //code
  }
});
```

---

As an aside, you don't need `await` here:

```
if (await jsonData.result.records.length !== 0) {
```

Don't just randomly sprinkle keywords around the code.  `await` is used for a specific purpose, to await the result of a Promise.  There's no Promise in this operation.

Comment: Thanks! Using .then fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually call `myFunction` and `await`/`.then`. If you just call it, it will return a `Promise` (because it's `async`) which is truthy. `await`ing it will give you the actual value

```js
if (await myFunction()) {
  // True
} else {
  // False
}
```

Comment: How can I use await outside of the function ?